# Can I put DDR5 RAM in my HP laptop

Tags: memory, upgrade, ddr3

I have a HP Pavilion G6 Laptop with 4GB RAM in one slot that is DDR3. Can I upgrade with DDR5 RAM on the other slot or will it not support it at all? I know DDR5 is also used in graphic cards but since it is very fast can it be installed on normal RAM slot? Or is there anything better than DDR3 that my laptop can support?

Comment: Graphics cards use **G** DDR5. GDDR and DDR are not the same.

Answer (score 7):

There are two reasons why you **cannot** do what you're proposing:

1. GDDR5 isn't available for computers; its designed specifically for graphics cards, and is completely different from DDR standards.
2. Computers only accept the type of memory they're designed for. For example, it is impossible to use DDR2 memory in a DDR3 computer, or vice versa.

Comment: A minor addition just for completeness sake:  There are a select few computers designed to work with multiple types of RAM. (e.g. with both DDR1 or DDR2, or with DDR2 or DDR3. E.g. some motherboards with AMD CPUs and AM2 sockets.) These are rare exceptions though and you could claim it is designed for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Every RAM type has its own socket with different pins/holes number and position, so even if there's DDR5 available, you can't put it in your memory slot

In short, RAM pinout is not forward and backward compatible

Answer (score 0):

Simply Put- **NO**.

There are a few reasons why this is not a thing that can be done;

1. DDR5 RAM is not really a thing that exists just yet, as the highest type of non-graphics RAM is DDR3. What you are saying that you would like to do is use graphics RAM in place of normal RAM which isn't possible... because graphics RAM is only available on graphics cards. simply enough.
2. As I just mentioned DDR5 doesn't exist yet, though if you are referring to ***G***DDR5, you would need to get a new graphics card to install such RAM, and chances are that your laptop doesn't support graphics card upgrades/ uses onboard graphics.

In other words, what you want to do is completely impossible. that's it.